# modify an apk without decompile it

Tags: php, android, download, tracking

I understand that this is an odd question, but I have this situation:

I serve an apk directly from a site, this apk has a `WebView` inside of it which will open a "secure" part of a website.

I would like to track down those who download it, and those who then open it, so I have thought of this:

I compile the apk with the URL written in this way (or in a similar one) :

www.myserver.com/secretplace/landing.php?token=##########

then, just before a user downloads it, I change those ########## characters with a token created on the fly and store in the database, when the user opens the apk, I can check the token and recognize that that was the user that downloaded the apk at that specific moment. I want to change it as if I load the apk in notepad and change it manually...

I really understand that this is odd, but...do you think it will work?

Does someone have some other idea on how to track users who download an apk for those who open it?

the question is: it is possible to modify an apk without decompile it? is there a problem? are there some limitations? such as, "yes you can modify it, but you must use the same number of characters" which could be acceptable.

NOTES: 
tha apk download and the fact the users MUST use APK to access the site is mandatory.

Comment: Also; you can check where your traffic comes from and on what OS it comes from (and ip address). Try finding a nice statistics plugin that is prebuilt that will provide this type of functionality...

Comment: well...becouse I have to do in this way... for some reasons that are not important for this question.
the ip is a little weak as solution, if the user passes from wifi to 3g, the ip changes, also, if he download the apk today, but open it tomorros, there is no way to know he is the same...

Comment: you could still have a membership system where the user can log in to the "secret" part of the site through a server-side database of users. That way you will know who it is.

Comment: we are not talking about "how user could access the site" this is already planned (sorry for this but I can't change this). My question is another.

Comment: From my understanding you want to track users correct? So then your question is being sufficiently answered... The best and most simplistic way around this would be to create some sort of server-side management of user accounts and that way when they log in you can associate android devices (APKs) with account names. Therefore you will then know when they download it and on what device they download it (Require a membership for downloads).

Comment: the question is: is it possible to modify an apk without decompile it? are there some limitation, does this idea of change the apk URL directly could work?

Comment: No. I do not know of anyway to modify a compiled APK. Especially since modifying it would require some sort of injections or the likewise which is against Google's code of conduct; now I realize you don't care about that since you are not putting this on the google store (I assume). You cannot simply "change a package". That sounds like malware...

Comment: it is not served via the google play, it is served directly from the website.

Comment: If you wanted the token system to work; you could always just store it in local user settings possibly after retrieving it from the server? (Generate a token on your site > push to android devices' local settings/device data).

Comment: I know that Matteo; that is why I stated that in the latter half of my sentence.

Comment: The problem is that local storage of the browser is different from th one of th apk.. and the need is to recofnize the user that download the apk. Well when a downloaded apk is opened

Comment: I'm not speaking of the browser. I'm talking about your webserver. Have the webserver do all the storing of tokens if you really want to use tokens; and then assign the server tokens to specific users that register. It could also manage the creation of tokens if you wanted.

Comment: The user will not register, downloading the apk must be the only tracking event :/

Comment: Sorry then; good luck with your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your question is very odd. Anyway, you can do that (in parts). The apk is a compressed folder and you can open it. But more part of code are compiled. But your assets are not. So, you can change some asset file and read it from your app. There is no secure here, but you could just use some log in system if you wanted that (Besides, anyway to use hash in apk will fail in secure because you can just copy the apk to another device).

There is other way. You can compile your apk on the fly. Use your webservice to change the code you want. Read this: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Well, I really recomend you to try some login system with tokens like [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) (but that is with you).

Comment: Sounds perfect. The build on the fly was another way. But takes too long if many requests are made simoultanousley.. so you know if  not compuled data is serialized or something.btw later i'll try :p

Comment: Yeah, but you can also let the server on night generating some builds for the day. Just a idea. But I think you liked to change the assets, will work too.

Comment: Well the apk copy could be nice too, because i can keep track of that partcular apk...